# Easy way to change your camera in ROS-gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The camera in my model does output a black-white image, and I do not know how to change it (it's quite a complicated model), therefore I've decided to change the camera to a different one.

I am wondering, what are the places in which I should do changes, except my .world file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267311/easy-way-to-change-your-camera-in-ros-gazebo/) by [kchledowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31224/kchledowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2017-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The camera will be somewhere in your robot model's file. That can either be a SDF file or a URDF file.

If it's a SDF file you can see what a camera tag looks like [here](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=sensor).

If it's a URDF file you can see what a camera tag looks like [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Camera).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1